# Number field sieve

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, cryptography, sieve-theory

I am a beginner in Number theory and Cryptography! Can someone please suggest a good article/paper to understand Quadratic Sieve and number Field Sieve thoroughly?

Comment: Also you could study the sources of a respected implementation like CADO-NFS (http://cado-nfs.gforge.inria.fr)

Comment: Related post by the same OP on MO: [Lattice Sieving](https://mathoverflow.net/q/268165).

Answer (score 3):

The book "Prime Numbers: A Computational Perspective" by Crandall and Pomerance has chapters on each of the two sieves, explaining them thoroughly.

In addition, Pomerance's article "A Tale of Two Sieves" gives an overview of both.

It is also easy to google lecture notes for both these sieves.